# RatingBar is unclickable

Tags: java, android, onclick, touch, ratingbar

I am trying to add a rating bar in my app so that one could rate a Question Object.

Here's my XML version of the rating bar:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="Question: "
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:gravity="center"/>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/fragment_question_string"
            android:layout_width="0sp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:hint="New question"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <RatingBar
        android:id="@+id/fragment_question_rating_bar"
        style="@style/Base.Widget.AppCompat.RatingBar.Small"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="true"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

And here's the part of my code where I am using the RatingBar in the onCreateView(LayoutInflater, View, Bundle) method of a fragment

```
RatingBar mRatingBar = (RatingBar) v.findViewById(R.id.fragment_question_rating_bar);
mRatingBar.setOnRatingBarChangeListener(new RatingBar.OnRatingBarChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onRatingChanged(RatingBar ratingBar, float rating, boolean fromUser) {
            int r = (int) rating;

            try {
                mQuestion.rateQuestion(r);
            } catch (IllegalRatingValue illegalRatingValue) {
                illegalRatingValue.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
```

The issue is that the rating bar is just unclickable. It doesn't change the number of stars when I try rating the question. It appears just like an image as it doesn't respond to touch. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

i have used these steps for taking the rating by user.

in xml

```
       <RatingBar
        android:id="@+id/ratingBar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:numStars="5"
        android:stepSize=".5"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:progressTint="@color/grey"
        android:progressBackgroundTint="@color/grey"
        android:secondaryProgressTint="@color/grey"
        android:rating="0.0" />
```

in Activity

RatingBar ratingBar=(RatingBar)findViewById(R.id.ratingBar);

float rating = ratingBar.getRating();

Comment: Doesn't work for me! I don't know why but the RatingBar is unclickable. I cannot even select two/three stars or anything

Answer (score 0):

Although your code didn't reflect it, this problem can sometimes be caused by having  `android:isIndicator="true"`.  Remove this entry for any case where you want the user to be able to change the rating.

Having the indicator set to true explicitly means that the user will not be able to change it.  Even if you have implemented a `new RatingBar.OnRatingBarChangedListener()`, the `onRatingChanged()` method will not fire.